# $T : M_{n \times n}(R) \rightarrow M_{n \times n}(R)$ and $T(A)= A^t$ and $ <A,B> = Tr(AB^t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V = M_{n \times n}(R)$ with the inner product $ <A,B> = Tr(AB^t)$, and $T$ the linear operator given by $T : M_{n \times n}(R) \rightarrow  M_{n \times n}(R)$ and $T(A)= A^t$ .

How can i find the minimal polynomial of T and the adjoint operator $T^t$.

I tried to compute the matrix associated of $T$. Any $A\in M_{n}$
has the form
$$
A=\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}e_{ij}\in M_{n}
$$
which is identified with 
$$
A=\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}e_{i}\otimes e_{j}\in\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}.
$$
Now, $T:\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$ by $e_{j}\otimes e_{i}\mapsto e_{i}\otimes e_{j}$,
i.e., 
$$
T=\sum_{i,j}e_{ij}\otimes e_{ji}
$$
For example, when $n=2$, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
e_{11}\otimes e_{11} & = & \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\\
e_{12}\otimes e_{21} & = & \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\\
e_{21}\otimes e_{12} & = & \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\\
e_{22}\otimes e_{22} & = & \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
But how an i get the general case? and get the minimal polynomial and characteristic of $T$ ?, and then can't find the minimal polynomial and the adjoint $T^t$, please i need help for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints.

**For the minimal polynomial.** Notice that $\mathrm{Sym}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathrm{Skew}_n(\mathbb{R})$ (the subspaces of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices) are eigenspaces of $T$. Moreover, we have
$$M_n(\mathbb{R})=\mathrm{Sym}_n(\mathbb{R}) \oplus \mathrm{Skew}_n(\mathbb{R})$$
This tells you that the operator $T$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\pm 1$. What does this say about the minimal polynomial? Alternatively, and perhaps more simply, notice that $T$ is an involution.

**For the adjoint.** The adjoint satisfies
$$\langle T(X),\ Y\rangle = \langle X^\mathrm{T},\ Y\rangle = \langle X,\ T^\mathrm{T}(Y)\rangle$$
But we also know that
$$\langle X^\mathrm{T},\ Y\rangle = \langle X, Y^\mathrm{T}\rangle$$
What does this tell you about the adjoint of $T$?

Comment: that is self adjoint

Comment: So, to find the characteristic polynomial, I'm trying to find the associated matrix of $T$. I did it for the case $n=2$. The coordinates of a matrix $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
c & d \end{array} \right)$ in the canonical basis $\beta$ is $[X]_\beta=\left( \begin{array}{c}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d \end{array} \right)$. Let

$$A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

Then

$$A[X]_\beta=[A^t]_\beta==\left( \begin{array}{c}
a \\
c \\
b \\
d \end{array} \right).$$

Comment: So, $A$ is the associated matrix of $T$. I know I can do the same for any $n$, but I don't know how to generalize it, and I need it to find the characteristic polynomial, solving $\det (\lambda I-A)=0$. Maybe there's an easier way to find the characteristic polynomial, if you know it, please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to find the characteristic polynomial or the minimal polynomial? Either way, my first hint should supply you with all the eigenvalues and should be sufficient for you to find either.